# Find address of minimum after a maximum

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, minimum

I have the following set of values in Column A of excel sheet.

```
0
99
159
199
225
242
254
262
267
270
271
269
266
259
249
238
224
208
193
178
166
156
151
150
150
150
150
150
150
150
```

0 is the minimum and 271 is the maximum for the entire column. A second minimum of 150 occurs after the maximum of 271. How may I find the address of the cell that first displays 150 in excel?

Comment: What if there is a 150 **before** the 271? Show expected results for your sample data or you are just wasting everyone's time with a game of 20 questions.

Comment: Are you just looking for the ***second-highest number** in the list?  Very confusing question.

Comment: @ashleedawg, I'm not looking at the second highest number. I want to find the location of the minimum that occurs after the maximum peak has reached.

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(MIN(INDEX(A:A, MATCH(MAX(A:A), A:A, 0)):INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, A:A))), INDEX(A:A, MATCH(MAX(A:A), A:A, 0)):INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, A:A)), 0)+MATCH(MAX(A:A), A:A, 0)-1, COLUMN(A:A), 4, 1, "sheet2")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The match function will return the row of the first found exact value.  Then you can add a "A" first to create the address.

```
=MATCH(150,A:A,0) = 24
```

then

```
="A"&MATCH(150,A:A,0) = A24
```

or:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(150,A:A,0),1)
```